# How to use SEF for both joomla and wordpress in same hosting?

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, joomla, joomla-sef-urls

I have a joomla website with SEF and now i try to install a wordpress blog in subfolder
(www.domainname.com/blog/). i edit the Permalink from wordpress cpanel and hi give me a code to put it inside (.htaccess) here the code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

after i put this code all joomla links start redirect to wordpress blog Except the main domain links (www.mydomain.com). so what i want to do to fix this issue

here the joomla SEF code

```
> ########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF SectionRewriteCondRewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
```

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution

just make a copy from .htaccess inside blog folder then replace the code that has it's own joomla SEF with wordpress SEF code.